# Assigning sections of search friendly URL into specific GET variables without HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am currently developing an application and I am using search friendly URLs as the basis for sending variables but I am confused as to how I can then assign a search friendly URL back to the specific GET variables so that they can be processed

From

```
http://localhost/users/categories/edit/1
```

To (internally)

```
http://localhost/index.php?section=users&subsection=categories&action=edit&id=1
```

Since the variables will be different for the various modules, the above variables cannot be hard coded into the .HTACCESS file.

Can this be achieved such that one just has to declare

```
$_GET['subsection'], $_GET['section']... etc
```

in the receiving file to get the respective variables?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, rewrite rules run before PHP code and cannot get inputs from your PHP code.

Comment: PHP does not receive and process HTTP requests. Apache does and it needs to know what file to retrieve. It will look for the specific file referred to by the URL, and if that doesn't exist then it returns a 404 error. The only way to capture any or all requests and modify them before calling a file is through Apache, either in the config file or *.htaccess*.

Comment: If you want it the way you want, then yes, they will have to be hardcoded in the config or .htaccess file. That's how it works. The files are not limited to 1 or 2 rules. There can be a 100. Personally I've had to do that to make all my modules SEF. But I didn't do them all. Just the ones that the user will see.

Comment: he could do this by abusing the: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable but i dont support this at all, also you need to explode on the '/', the problem: they wont be in the $_GET